# Adding custom ListView to Alert dialog

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I want to add custom list view too a alert dialog it works fine when i select a item from list and click the (setPositiveButton) the dialog close and the text is changed successful but when i click again on the passenger button to view or for change selection than application stops unfortunately

```
public void onClick(View v) {               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setView(v);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.setView(listView);
            AlertDialog dialog= builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have dumped some code here, but what is your question? What do you want to achieve, what is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

Please try these for setting list view inside alert dialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder   alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
 LayoutInflater inflaterr = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View  viewtemplelayout= inflaterr.inflate(R.layout.product_popup, null);
    YourAdapter adap=new YourAdapter(R.layout.product_add_popup_adapter,context);
    list.setAdapter(adap);
     alertdialog.setView(viewtemplelayout);
     alertdialog.show()
```

i think it help full for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);

        List<Requests> requester = new ArrayList<>();
        final NameAdapter AlertDialogueAdapter = new NameAdapter(this, R.layout.your_custom_layout, requester);

        AlertDialogueBuilder.add(new Requests("Hello","StackOverF"))
        builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.avatar);
        builderSingle.setTitle("Select Message by,");
        builderSingle.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });
        builderSingle.setAdapter(AlertDialogueAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Requests req = AlertDialogueAdapter.getItem(which);
                AlertDialog.Builder builderInner = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewSpecialMessage.this);
                builderInner.setMessage(req.getKey());
                builderInner.setTitle(req.getName());
                builderInner.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                builderInner.show();
            }
        });
        builderSingle.show();

public class Requests{
    private String name;
    private String key;
    public Requests(){

    }
    public Requests(String name, String key){
        this.name = name;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
public class NameAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Requests>{

    public NameAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Requests> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.name_adapter_layout, parent, false);
        }
        final Requests message = getItem(position);
        TextView NameOfRequester = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RequesterName);
        ImageView ImgOfRequester = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RequesterImage);
        NameOfRequester.setText(message.getName());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Create costom adapter by extending the class as ArrayAdapter(its in your case)

Override getView() function(also inflate the view).

After that you can directly set adapter by using

```
 builder.setAdapter(costomAdapter);
```